# How to create own extended user form?

Tags: django, forms

I have django model that extending User:

```
class Student(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
   #other field in that profile
   #other field in that profile
   #other field in that profile
```

In settings.py have added:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'myapp.Student'
```

Now i want have some form on my site to creating that Student-user. What is the simpliest way to do it?
I don't know did i should create ModelForm, forms.Form or something else in forms.py.
Also i dont know how to validate this form in views.py file. I want only add new user with this student extra fields.
I still trying some ways but nothing works!
Please help!

I'm using Django1.2.5

Answer (score 6):

Are you going to let your user access this form through the Admin site?

If so, then the simplest solution to combine the 2 forms (User and Student) would be to use the Inline model in the Admin site.

**Solution 1** (simplest - use Admin site, [as document here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from testapp.myauth.models import Student
from testapp.myauth.forms import UserForm

class StudentInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Student

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [
        StudentInline,
    ]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Now if you don't like that solution because it doesn't look pretty, or you don't use the admin site, you can do it the hard way and combine the 2 forms seamlessly (you won't see that it's 2 different forms). This method was derived from this [great snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2081/).

**Solution 2** (the more advanced method - seamless form combination):

**models.py**

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=10)

# Create student instance on access - very useful if you plan to always have a Student obj associated with a User object anyway
User.student = property(lambda u: Student.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm

from testapp.myauth.models import Student

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student

class UserForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        student_kwargs = kwargs.copy()
        if kwargs.has_key('instance'):
            self.student = kwargs['instance'].student
            student_kwargs['instance'] = self.student
        self.student_form = StudentForm(*args, **student_kwargs)
        self.fields.update(self.student_form.fields)
        self.initial.update(self.student_form.initial)

        # define fields order if needed
        self.fields.keyOrder = (
            'last_name',
            'first_name',
            # etc
            'address',
        )


    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UserForm, self).clean()
        self.errors.update(self.student_form.errors)
        return cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.student_form.save(commit)
        return super(UserForm, self).save(commit)
```

So what I did here was to create StudentForm instance within the UserForm, and combine their fields accordingly.

My only suggestion to you is that consider renaming your profile model to something more generic instead of Student (e.g. UserProfile would work) as you never know if in the future you may end up having different types of users, other students (e.g. teacher).

Answer (score 0):

You would most likely want to create two ModelForms.
You can handle them both in one view.  Simply save the User object first,
then add that user to your Student object that's created from your modelform on POST.

Check out [this post,](http://uswaretech.com/blog/2010/01/doing-things-with-django-forms/) specifically problem 7 on that page for details.